# GraphQL requests from React frontend aren't making it to the server

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm working on an application that uses React for the client and Apollo Express for the server, and for some reason GraphQL requests are not making it to the server. I have a sign-up form; when I enter information and press submit, all the data is being collected correctly, but for some reason when I call the function returned by useMutation, it returns null. In the browser console I get the following error: `Response not successful: Received status code 404`.

By putting console.logs in the relevant resolver I found that it wasn't running when I pressed submit. However, if I go to the `localhost:3001/graphql` endpoint, I *can* perform mutations successfully; the resolvers themselves work. I have another, working application with a React frontend and Apollo Express backend, but referencing or even copying in code from there has been no help.

Here's every code chunk I can imagine is relevant:

`client/src/App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {ApolloProvider, ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink} from '@apollo/client';
import {setContext} from '@apollo/client/link/context';

import Splash from './components/Splash';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.js';
// import Resources from './components/Resources.js';

// hook up the client to the graphql endpoint
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: '/graphql'
});

// attach authorization property to every request
const authLink = setContext((_, {headers}) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');

    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
        }
    };
});

// instantiate apollo w/ cache
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <Splash />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Splash />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          {/*<Route exact path="/resources" element={Resources} />*/}
          <Route render={() => <h1 className="display-2">Wrong page!</h1>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`client/src/components/SignupModal.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Auth from '../utils/auth';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import { ADD_USER } from '../utils/mutations';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './LoginModal.css';

function SignUp() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: '',
    email: '',
  });
  const { username, password, email } = formState;

  const [addUser, { error }] = useMutation(ADD_USER);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setFormState({ ...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('ERROR', error);
    try {
      const mutationResponse = await addUser({
        variables: {
          username: formState.username,
          email: formState.email,
          password: formState.password,
        },
      });
      // any console.logs after this point don't run

      const token = mutationResponse.data.addUser.token;
      Auth.login(token);

      <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace={true} />;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    [...]
  );
}

export default SignUp;
```

`client/src/utils/mutations.js`:

```
import {gql} from '@apollo/client';

export const ADD_USER = gql`
mutation addUser($username: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
    addUser(username: $username, email: $email, password: $password) {
        token
        user {
            _id
            username
            email
        }
    }
}
`;
```

`server/server.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const {ApolloServer} = require('apollo-server-express');
const path = require('path');

const {typeDefs, resolvers} = require('./schemas');
const {authMiddleware} = require('./utils/auth');
const db = require('./config/connection');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: authMiddleware
});
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const startApolloServer = async (typeDefs, resolvers) => {
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({app});
}

// if we're in production, serve client/build as static assets
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
};

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
});

db.once('open', () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`API server running on port ${PORT}!`);
        console.log(
            `Use GraphQL at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`
        );
    });
});

startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers);
```

`server/schemas/resolvers.js`:

```
const { User } = require('../models');
const { signToken } = require('../utils/auth');

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    [...]
  },
  Mutation: {
    addUser: async (_, args) => {
      // console.logs here run if i run this mutation in apollo studio, but not if i try to call it from the frontend
      const user = await User.create(args);
      const token = signToken(user);
      return { token, user };
    }
  }
};

module.exports = resolvers;
```

Comment: You know what 404 means, so you should be able to debug this yourself. If you're able to make GraphQL queries at one endpoint, use the Chrome developer tools to verify which URL is being POST-ed to in the network tab. Then compare that to what endpoint your faulty page is hitting.

Comment: @AndyRay The request is going to localhost:3000/graphql. I don't know how to change this.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I had forgotten to add a proxy value to the client's package.json - `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"`. That fixed it.